# Cómo personalizar vídeo online y enviar por mail

Tags: php, html

Necesito enviar mails que incluyan un vídeo personalizado, con los datos recogidos desde un formulario.

Me explico:
Paso 1: El usuario accede a un enlade en el que rellena un formulario online con sus datos y su foto de perfil.

Paso 2. la foto subida desde el formulario se inserta automáticamente en un vídeo, que de esta forma queda personalizado.

Paso 3. Automáticamente, al enviar el formulario, se envía un mail con los datos recogidos en el formulario + el vídeo personalizado.

¿Cuál sería la forma de llevarlo a cabo? ¿Es posible hacerlo con php o sería necesaria alguna aplicación?

Adjunto la parte de código que tengo implementada: el usuario inserta una foto, que se envía junto con el resto de datos al email del destinatario. Lo que quiero conseguir es que esa foto se inserte en un vídeo y éste se envíe por mail.

Index.html

```html
<form class="form" id="form" name="form" method="post" action="mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="Aname" name="aname" type="text"  value="" placeholder="Tu nombre" required="true">
    <input id="Amail" name="amail" type="text" value="" placeholder="Tu email" required="true">  
 <input id="Bname" name="bname" type="text"  value="" placeholder="Nombre del destinatario" required="true">
    <input id="Bmail" name="bmail" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email del destinatario" required="true">  
 <input id="img" name="img" type="file" required="true">
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

Mail.php

```html
<?php        
$foto = $_FILES['img']['name'];
copy($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],'/img/$foto');
             
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
   <head>
    <title>
    TIENES UN MENSAJE
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>';

$message .= '<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   '.strip_tags($_POST['aname']).' te envía su foto
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   DE: 
  </td>
  <td>
   '.strip_tags($_POST['aname']).' - '.strip_tags($_POST['amail']).'
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img id="photo" class="photo" src="/img/'.$foto.'">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>';

$message .= "</body>
</html>";
$to = strip_tags($_POST['bmail']);
$subject = 'De parte de '.strip_tags($_POST['aname']);
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['amail']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['bmail']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";  
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) 
?>
```

Comment: Con tal descripción sin nada de apollo no te podemos ayudar. Adjunta lo que lleves escrito y entonces te podremos echar un cable tal y como está la pregunta es realmente dificil.

Comment: Hola María si compartieras algo del codigo que tienes podriamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Deberias de editar la pregunta y agregar un poco de lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que deseas hacer necesitarías algo más que PHP, en este caso la herramienta que conozco personalmente se llama **FFmpeg**.

Con la combinación de estas podrás editar un video y poner una imagen en una zona específica de dicho video. Esto quiere decir que si es por ejemplo una cara y se va moviendo en el video, tendrás que ir cambiando la cara a la nueva posición.

Te dejo un [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936161/insert-image-into-mp4-video-by-php) de este mismo foro pero en inglés donde dan un buen ejemplo de como hacerlo.